# Multiline Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I am not a big fun of regexps but this time I can't avoid them.

I have to match each line of the following text, so that each line is a match

```
️Winners in this draw️
John VN:Odd5=9.9 Pair3=6
iiiddd:Odd1=1.98
aaaxxx:Dragon10=21 Odd20=39.6
GeralynAguilar:Big4=7.92
----------
```

There is a player on each line.

Foreach Player there is his name:all_the_bets_he_placed separated by space.

Foreach bet there is bet_name=amount_he_won

I need all the above mentioned fields and have written the, probably ugly, regex

```
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<player>(?<name>[^:]+):(?<allbets>(?<onebet>(?<betname>[^=\s]*)=(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)\s?))+)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture| RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

The regex is matching only one match, but if I add a space at the end of each line everything is working properly. I can't understand why.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with all strings specified in code.

Comment: Can you include the code where you use the regular expression as I'm seeing it capture everything even without spaces at the ends of each line.

Comment: *Raw*, meant to be multiline: `(.+?):(\w*)=([\d.]+)(?=\s*(\w*)=*([\d.]+)|$)` (just written here, no named groups, not tested at all).

Answer (score 1):

This is not elegant in terms of Regex, but I tested it and it works:

```
\uD83D\uDC49(?<player>[^:]+):(?<bet1name>[^:=]+)=(?<bet1value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s(?<bet2name>[^:=]+)=(?<bet2value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?
```

However, Regex isn't the best choice for this particular problem. First, you know each result is on a separate line, second, you know each player's name and their bets is separated by a colon, next, you know that the bets are separated by spaces, and finally, the name and value of the bets are separated by equal signs. So...

I would split the strings.

`Split('\n')` the text to get a `string[]` array, then loop the array. If the line starts with the emoji, `Substring()` past the emoji to get just the relevant text, then `Split(':')`, that'll give you a `string[]` array with the player name at index 0, and the bets at index 1. Then `Split(' ')` the bets to get each bet individually as another `string[]` array. Finally, `Split(' ')` each bet to get one last `string[]` array with the bet name at index 0 and the bet value at index 1.

You can wrap that into a method which can spit it all out into a `List<>` of a custom class that'll strong type the bet values into a Decimal.

Comment: yes splitting by : and spaces is also a good idea. but your regex doesn't work, the bets placed by each player are virtually unlimited.

Comment: I figured as much. I tried to illustrate how you could do it as a single Regex. For unlimited matches, it won't work because a capturing group will always hold only one match. What you'd need to do if you wanted to do it with Regex is run two passes. The first pass to extract the player's name, and then the second pass for all the bets, but then you'll have a hard time matching the bets to the players, hence why I recommend splitting the strings instead.